# What are my options for dealing with/getting rid of storage items I do not want/need?

Tags: transportation

I am moving into a new house and have some movers moving all of my stuff out of storage and bringing it into my house. Unfortunately, there are some large furniture items (couch, table, etc...) that I do not want/need in my new place. I am apathetic about what happens to these items. Ideally, I'd like to give them to charity, but do not want (nor have the means) to drive them to a charity location. I could throw them out, but again I do not have the means to transport them a disposal site. I could sell them (via Facebook marketplace or something) but I do not want them placed in my house because it will be difficult to move them out of the house once they are inside and finding a buyer may take a while. Can I just leave them outside? Will the moving company even allow me to elect to have them not be moved into my home? What can I do? Keeping them in storage is not an option.

Comment: Some charities will come and pickup large items. You should check if any local ones do. I think Volunteers of America will. If the location in your other profiles is still accurate, you might want to Google "Houston TX charities that pick up"

Comment: Flagging to close as too broad (and not *really* "Home Improvement").  I'd say local charity, Freecycle, eBay, etc.  (Start looking for takers now.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about home improvement as defined by this network.

Comment: Check with the storage facility.  They may have an empty unit you can move the unwanted items to so they can sell it in their next auction.  I did this with some furniture the last time I moved out of one and it worked well.  They did not want trash, but were fine to keep anything usable.

Answer (score 4):

You are responsible to see the items all the way to their final disposition.

Yes, it's a pain, but you have to do it.

- You can ask the city if they can do a special garbage pickup.
- You can call your normal garbage company and ask them about a special pickup.
- You can rent a dumpster short-term and fill that.
- You can ask your movers to dispose of the items in their dumpster, *however, if they dump the items down some alley instead, and the government catches you, you will be fined heavily even though you acted in good faith*.
- You can hire "get rid of your junk" companies to make it go away; they may try where possible to profit from its sale, however the same warning applies.
- You can put a "free stuff" listing on Craigslist, Freecycle, Nextdoor etc.  -- but if the stuff is not taken, you are still responsible for its disposal.
- If you are renting, you can walk away from the stuff.  The landlord will hire movers to remove it, and bill the cost of this to you.

Taking the items to Goodwill/charity is probably a lose; they are glutted with excess furniture, so they are very picky what they'll take.

If you abandon the items at a house you are selling, it could interfere with closing, and at least, the buyer could sue you in small claims for the disposal costs.  "Broom clean" is the standard for both sold houses and rentals; look it up.

My best advice is if you don't want to dispose of it, don't buy it in the first place.

Comment: 1-800-got-junk,

Answer (score 1):

When I have things I no longer want I place it by the curb and post on Nextdoor for anyone to pick it up. Even good stuff I would rather give away than to try and plan all that it takes to try and make money. I also call all of the charities and most will pick up. Recently Goodwill picked up some things but they would not take my chairs because they had worn places and they had no way to repair it but the structure was in good shape so I advertise on Nextdoor for it to be used in a camp house or garage area. Usually if I put them in my alley people who have rear entry drives will see them and they rarely stay more than a day.

Answer (score 0):

Post an ad (online and/or wherever is free to sell that stuff), sell them for free with one condition, the buyer must pick up the item/s at that specific location. There are always people looking for that kind of stuff for free. Don't know if you're in a rush or not, but there are always people willing to collect stuff to use it, to donate it to somebody even to resell it. Even you could contact with a charity organization an offer your stuff for free with that condition.